# When is a subset of {0,1} valued borel functions on a standard borel space (polish space) complete (see *) under the pointwise convergence topology?

Tags: analysis, topological-vector-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

*In other words, what restrictions on a family F of {0,1} valued borel functions will tell us that the pointwise limit of any net in F is borel. I feel like there must be lots known about this but I cannot seem to find anything.